# How to retrieve checked checkbox with my code?

Tags: php, mysql, post

HTML CODE :

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Jaywalking'  /> 
Jaywalking<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Littering'/> 
Littering<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Illegal Vendor' /> 
Illegal Vendor
```

POST CODE:

```
if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation_save=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation_save=$_POST['cbox'];

mysql_query("UPDATE tblcitizen SET violation='$violation_save' WHERE id='$id'") or die mysql_error());
```

What is the easiest way to retrieve checked checkbox value into the database? What is the proper way to retrieve it base on my code?

Comment: Are the values getting `POST`ed correctly? If so `print_r($_POST);` should get you started.

Comment: is_array($_POST['cbox'] will always be true if data is set (1 or more)

Comment: Have you done a var_dump of $_POST['cbox']? That should clear things up for you in terms of understanding what values are passed.

Comment: @AmalMurali : i tried that one before but nothing happens :(

Comment: @Undefined_variable : can't understand sir XD please elaborate im a beginner sir

Comment: @user3397748: Then it means the values are *not* getting posted. Please show us the full HTML markup (the `<form> ... </form>` part)

Comment: @MikeBrant how to do that sir?

Comment: <form method="post">
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Jaywalking'  /> 
Jaywalking<br>

                        <input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Littering'/> 
Littering<br>


                        <input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Illegal Vendor' /> 
Illegal Vendor
</form>

that is my form sir

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280485/how-to-fetch-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Jaywalking'  /> 
Jaywalking<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Littering'/> 
Littering<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Illegal Vendor' /> 
Illegal Vendor
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $violation_save = '';
    if(is_array($_POST['cbox']))
        $violation_save=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']);
    else
        $violation_save=$_POST['cbox'];
    //debug purpose
    var_dump($violation_save);
    $sql = "UPDATE `tblcitizen` SET `violation`='$violation_save' WHERE `id`='$id'";
    var_dump($sql);
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

This just demonstrates on the values being stored in `$_POST['cbox']` which is shown as output using `var_dump`

Comment: sir is this code will retrieve the checkbox coming from the database and it will be checked if it has a record?

Comment: Values in variable `$_POST` comes from HTTP Request only which is of `METHOD - POST`, here we are not referring to database and so we cannot consider that. `name='cbox[]'` means we are stating that variable to be acted as array which will contain all the checked values, and you can insert these values in database by doing iteration over this array example: `foreach($_POST['cbox'] as $cbox_val)`

Comment: if (!$result) 
  {
  die("Error: Data not found..");
  }
    $id=$test['id'] ;
    $license= $test['license'] ;     
    $stickerno=$test['stickerno'] ;
    $fname=$test['fname'] ;
    $mname= $test['mname'] ;     
    $lname=$test['lname'] ;
    $no=$test['no'] ;
    $street= $test['street'] ;     
    $city=$test['city'] ;
    $bdate=$test['bdate'] ;
  $violationplace=$test['violationplace'] ;
    $dd=$test['dd'] ;
    $mm=$test['mm'] ;
    $yy=$test['yy'] ;
    $hh=$test['hh'] ;
    $min=$test['min'] ;
    $ampm=$test['ampm'] ;
    $type=$test['type'] ;
    $officer=$test['officer'] ;

Comment: Can't understand what you want to say from this code

Comment: that is my retrieving method sir. and i'll use <?php echo $fname?>

Comment: Your above post code in question seems to be good, what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @user3397748 I have edited the code to identify the values for debug purpose can u please refer in my answer

Comment: sir i want to fetch checked values from the database