# How to fetch checkbox

Tags: php, post, fetch

This is my HTML code:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Jaywalking'/> 
Jaywalking<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Littering'/> 
Littering<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Illegal Vendor'/> 
Illegal Vendor
```

This is my posting code:

```
if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) 
   $violation_save=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); 
else 
   $violation_save=$_POST['cbox'];

mysql_query("UPDATE tblcitizen SET violation='$violation_save' WHERE id='$id'") or die mysql_error());
```

How can I fetch the selected values from the database?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: I am not shouting sir @aksu my keyboard is malfunctioning :( im sorry

Comment: sir @Md.SahadatHossain: i want to retrieve the checked values from the database

Comment: Okay @user3397748 I edited your post.

Comment: This answer will be helpful [Multiple Checkboxes in PHP][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should NOT use the mysql_* functions of php anymore. These functions are marked as deprecated and will be removed in the next major php release.

So if $_POST['cbox'] is an array, you must handle it as an array.

```
// how to save checked values
try {
    $db = new PDO(...);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE yourTable SET myField = :myField WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id' , $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    foreach ($_POST['cbox'] as $myField) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':myField', $myField);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // error handling
}

// how to fetch checked values
try {
    $myValues = array();
    $db = new PDO(...);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT myField FROM myTable WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        $myValues[] = $row['myField'];
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // error handling
}

// HTML Part
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="bla"<?php if (in_array('bla', $myValues)) { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> />
```

Just have a look at the php manual for PDO or the MySQLi extension.

Comment: sir how can I fetch the checked values? and display it as checked?

Comment: enhanced the answer with an example for displaying checked values fetched from database.

Comment: i'll just copy the code sir and i'll just paste it :) thank you sir :) i'll try it